# Using \docsvlist on a generated list with newcommand

Tags: etoolbox

Good evening,

I tried to adapt an example code in `etoolbox` and could not make it work. An example is most probably easier to understand :

while

```
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
\docsvlist{item1, item2, item3}
\end{itemize}
```

given in the documentation works just fine, I cannot understand why this

```
\newcommand{\test}{item1, item2, item3}

\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
\docsvlist{\test}
\end{itemize}
```

will not process the list as 3 items but just one.

I need it in a more complex situation but my basic problem is here. (The `\test` is defined somewhere else in my case but I do not think it is relevant).

Sorry if my English and/or LaTeX is a bit shaky, I am not a native in either...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You need to expand test first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\test` is not expanded, i.e. it is not seen as a csv - list with three items but as a single entity.

Solution: Use `\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\test}`.

The first `\expandafter` tells `TeX` to look **after** `\docsvlist`, there must be another `\expandafter` in order to look **after** the `{` and then expand `\test`.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\test}{item1,item2,item3}


\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\renewcommand*{\do}[1]{\item #1}
\expandafter\docsvlist\expandafter{\test}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This uses `expl3` features by storing the list into a `\clist` variable and 'preventing' expansion issues:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\clist_new:N \l_sandrine_item_clist 
\NewDocumentCommand{\SetMyList}{+m}{
  \clist_set:Nn \l_sandrine_item_clist {#1}
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\listmapper}{}{%
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l_sandrine_item_clist {\item ##1}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\SetMyList{item 1,item 2,item 3}

\begin{itemize}
\listmapper
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```